# IndexedDBShim works for a bit, then produces errors

Tags: javascript, html, indexeddb, web-sql

I have a fairly data-intensive mobile app based on HTML5 / Javascript using IndexedDb and the IndexedDbShim for devices which do not support idb natively.

For devices that support IndexedDb, the application is fine with no data access problems. However when testing on an iPad Mini using Safari, although the application initially runs ok, browsing around and using the application in its usual way "randomly" throws up the following errors:

- Unable to open database (14 unable to open database file)
- InvalidStateError: DOM Exception: An attempt was made to use an object that is not, or is no longer, usable.

Has anyone had this kind of problem before using the IndexedDbShim?

Comment: Can you show us how you fill the db? Make sure to not open a transaction and later use it in an async block. For example, first opening a transaction and after that a ajax request where you will try to use it might give the error you are seeing.

Comment: Is this the Dick van den Brink who authors the github Indexeddbshim project? Nice to meet you! Interesting about the transaction idea. I'll have a look at exactly how we manage the transactions.

Comment: Yep that is me :) The Original author is someone else btw so most of the credit should go to Parashuram :)

Comment: Dick come join us on the IndexedDB Users list! We'd love to start community building around IDB https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/indexeddb-users

Comment: Jonny I'm sorry not to be able to help you, but I'll try to research this shim. In the meantime, try wrapping each isolate transaction into an immediately executed anonymous function closure. I'm not a WebSQL guy, but it sounds like you have possible transaction autocommit issues.

Comment: Unfortunately i am unable to provide code as this is part of a commercial application. How would I track transaction usage? I switched on debugging in the shim, but could not see anything obvious with transaction commit issues. One further problem is with the shim performance. We have an object store with 7000 records. When pulling them out with native IndexedDb it's very quick, but when we use Safari, it's painfully slow (as in several minutes) and it prevents any other data access until it finishes.

Answer (score 1):

Are you closing your transactions?

I got these types of errors in my tests because I wasn't closing the database and transactions after use.

Only on shimmed browsers.